# Can I make icons smaller on a bq Aquaris e5 Ubuntu Edition?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, icons, resize

It's all on the title 
But I need more characters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went through the entire ubuntu-phone mailing list if anyone ever brought up making icons smaller and: nope …

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news!*

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**